# How do I resolve : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_bip.default.generateMnemonic')

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm working on a mobile application and I need to use bip39 in order to generate a passphrase, after installing the package some errors of the following missing packages popped out : `stream buffer events`, after installing everything, I came across this error :

> [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_bip.default.generateMnemonic')]

Here is how I'm using bip39 :

```
import bip39 from 'bip39'
export default function NewAccount({ navigation }) {

const handleSubmit = async () => {
try {
  let seed = await bip39.generateMnemonic(256) // default to 128
  console.log(seed)
  return seed
   } catch(e) {
  console.log(e)

  }
 navigation.navigate("Passphrase")
 }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
import bip39 from 'bip39'
```

to

```
import * as bip39 from 'bip39'
```